# Youtube objective c api

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube-api, google-authentication

Hello anyone got any idea where I can find an api/sample code that I can use to authenticate with youtube?

I found the following http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/checkout

but it is for mac applications. Anyone knows where I can find the iPhone related stuff?

I am just trying to authenticate with YOUTUBE and grab the authtoken.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this url: http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction
I think it can help you.

Comment: Cheers I missed that one. Looks useful.